# How do I call a Var from different file?

Tags: javascript

Hi so I am trying at the moment to call another var list that I have created in another file I have currently tried using

```
var random = requre('./random.js');
```

inside the main file and the second file with the variable list is named random.js how do I call the var inside this file into the first file?

here is how my variable looks: {this code does have stuff in it}

```
var randomlist = ['', '', ''];
```

Comment: if both scripts are loaded at the same time and your variable in script 1 is global, script 2 will have access to it

Comment: Script one has all the main code script two has the var with the list...

Comment: it is not in a function

Comment: @IrkenInvader: No; these are modules.  They must be exported.

Comment: @KstreakOG: You aren't using requirejs.  Please add the correct tag.

Comment: someone else added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your random.js file you need a module.exports
e.g.

```
var MY_VARIABLE=69
module.exports = {"MY_VARIABLE":MY_VARIABLE}
```

Comment: then How would I import it?

Comment: the same way you did before, with the require

Comment: then how do i call it to use that variable like in text do i make a new var ?